# Combine different index types in postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, postgresql-9.6

we have query for fulltext where we have also another condition. Can you tell me what is correct usage of multiple indexes of different type?

for instance:

```
select * from foo_tbl foo
where foo.bar_tsv @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'xxx & yyy')
and foo.reg_date is null 
and foo.is_active = true;
```

I have created index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_fts_idx ON foo_tbl
USING GIN(bar_tsv);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX foo_active_idx ON foo_tbl(is_active);
CREATE INDEX foo_reg_date_idx ON foo_tbl(reg_date);
```

when I execute query plan with `EXPLAIN` command I find out there is hit only full text index, can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

EDIT:

Output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_tbl foo (cost=44.55..323.29 rows=71 width=2963) (actual time=0.475..0.497 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (foo_tsv @@ '''xxx '':* & ''yyy'''::tsquery)"
"  Filter: ((reg_date IS NULL) AND is_active)"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=3"
"  Buffers: shared hit=24 read=4"
"  I/O Timings: read=0.089"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_fts_idx   (cost=0.00..44.53 rows=71 width=0) (actual time=0.412..0.412 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (foo_tsv @@ '''xxx'':* & ''yyy'''::tsquery)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=24 read=1"
"        I/O Timings: read=0.014"
"Planning time: 4.977 ms"
"Execution time: 0.578 ms"
```

There is not used index for is_active nor reg_date.

Comment: From the data type of `is_active`, there are chances that the index won't be used ever (unless it's true only in a small amount of rows).  But the main question is: why do you think it would be better to use two indexes?  What does `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` tell you about the query performance?

Comment: What percentage of your table is_active?

Comment: @dezso I added into question output of explain

Comment: @jjanes about 50%

Comment: PostgreSQL will automatically combine indexes when it thinks it is beneficial.  There is no reason to think it will be beneficial in this case.